# Windows Service for launching and restarting a user process (with GUI)

Tags: c++, user-interface, windows-services, impersonation

I need a certain process to be constantly running in every user’s computer. If that .exe is killed, I must be able to restart it and send an alert.
I immediately thought of building a Windows Service as the ideal solution, but I am facing a problem:

- The process started by that service needs to be able to interact with the user, e.g. be able to show him a GUI.
- my application also sets a keyboard hook in order to monitor [the user's typing rhythms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics), and when I start the .exe from a service, that information is not accessible.

From the service I am able to launch the process "as the user" (using the LogonUser and CreateProcessAsUser functions), but still can’t see the GUI.
Is this possible? If not, what can I use to achieve the desired functionality?

tia

Comment: I believe that in Windows 7 it's no longer possible for a service to interact with the desktop.  I could be wrong on this.

Answer (score 3):

By default the GUI .exe will be run in the service session, which is separate from the interactive session of the user. You need to look into techniques for building an [interactive service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks. The solution described in the "Interacting with a User from a Service Indirectly" section easily solves the problem of showing dialogs, but unfortunately my application also sets a keyboard hook in order to monitor [the user's typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics), and when I start the .exe from a service, that information is not accessible.  I have updated my question with this additional issue.